# how to increment for loop count if a condition fails in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop something like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < loop.length; i++) {  //line1
    if(a == b) {                        //line2
        //someAction_1
    }
    else if (x[i] == "myString") {
        //someAction_2
    }
    else {                             //line7
        //someAction_3
    }
}
```

If the condition in `else if` fails it should go back to beginning of `for` loop and increment `i` by `+1`. After all the condition fails in `else if` it should execute `else` condition. Like for example considering `i=3` for first iteration it checks `x[1]== "myString"` but that condition is false. So instead of going to next line i.e., instead of executing `else` statement it should go back and increment `i` by 1 and start executing `if` condition(line2) from beginning. Once the loop count (third iteration) is 3 and if `x[3]=="myString` is also false then execute `else` statement (line7)

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They're different programming languages.

Comment: please add the content of `loop` and other missing variables.

Comment: @evolutionxbox JavaScript

Comment: Consider `if(!x.includes['myString"))` - [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @NinaScholz what content exactly??I just need logic. Hopefully, my question is clear enough

Comment: please add a small amount of data and the wanted outcome of it. if you want different outcome, add more data to show the difference.

Comment: @NinaScholz have edited the question

Comment: it does not help to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

more content or data would be helpful but you can try below logic....

```
for(var i = 0; i < loop.length; i++) {
    if(a == b || x[i] == "myString") {
        //someAction_1
    }

    else {
        //someAction_3
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not understanding what more content/data is needed. Anyways in your solution during first iteration when it checks `a==b || x[1]=="myString"` the output of `if `condition is `0/false`. Now instead of going to else statement I need to skip that and continue with next iteration. At the last iteration in case `a==b || x[i]=="myString"` turns out false...Then execute `else` statement

Comment: content data means have a working example with actual output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is simply a flag variable with an additional `if` condition at the end of the loop.

```
function findMatches(arr, matchString, condition=false) {
    let foundMatch = false;
    for(let [i, v] of arr.entries()) {
        if(condition) {
            console.log("The condition is true so not checking for match");
        }
        else if (v === matchString) {
            console.log("Found a match at", i);
            foundMatch = true;
        }
    }
    if(!foundMatch) {
        console.log("No match was found");
    }
}
findMatches(["a", "b", "c"], "a") // Found a match at 0
findMatches(["a", "b", "c"], "d") // No match was found
let a = b = 10;
findMatches(["a", "b", "c"], "a", a == b) // The condition is true so not checking for match / No match was found
```

Alternatively you could use `let matchIndex = x.indexOf("myString")` to identify the first occurrence of the string and `if(matchIndex == -1)` to test if none of the values in `x` match the string.